# Is it possible to drive an arduino nano and a 5v solenoid via usb?

Tags: arduino, solenoid, arduino-uno

So basically i want to make a clicker with a solenoid like an old school IBM keyboard. What i'm thinking is to put and arduino nano and the smallest 5v solenid i can find inside my keyboard and internally connect the usb power lines to the arduino and the solenoid, but i'm worried it'll be enough power consumption to fry a usb 2.0 port. The arduino nano uses around 19mA and my keyboard 100mA. I'm an absolute noob when it comes to anything other than coding (i do know how to solder propperly tho).

Edit:
Thanks for your comments, i think i'll be doing exactly as i said EXCEPT i'll use an external power supply for the solenoid/arduino and investigate on how to make a propper prottection circuit so that i don't accientally fry my arduino or my keyboard.

Comment: I wouldn't connect anything like this to my USB ports without sufficient protection. Solenoids might cause huge current spikes that are not very healthy to electronics.

Comment: When you decide which solenoid you want to use, edit your question to add a link to the manufacturer's datasheet. Then we can give you advice.

Comment: @savyexe eidt your question and write a specific question. Is it possible is not a great way to pose a question.

Comment: *Is it possibe..* questions can be answered with yes/no. But the real question is, **if it is a good idea to do it like this and that...** Often things are **possible** but that does not mean it is a **good idea**. Suppose there are better / more clever ways. You might want to learn about that, right? So ask: "Is this the way to drive an Arduino....?"

Comment: If all you want from the solenoid is a clicking noise, look at 5V relays which will be relatively low power and definitely compatible with USB.

Comment: If it's just a clicker you could use a speaker or you could charge up a capacitor and discharge it into the solenoid to pulse it without taking excessive current from the 5V power.